# Why is _CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter being called instead of being caught by catch(...)

Tags: c, exception, visual-studio-2005

I've had this problem with msvcrt and no also msvcr80.dll. A _CxxThrowException is going to the unhandled exception filter.

Shouldn't catch(...) catch this???

Comment: Can you provide some more information and perhaps code, because like this, it's hard to say why.

Comment: Can you post the revalent code?

Answer (score 1):

C++ require your method/function definition to precisely declare what it can throw to allow catch(...) to work. I know it seems crazy, that the catch-all model does not in fact do what you expect, but this is by design

Answer (score 0):

A `_CxxThrowException` is a Microsoft specific low-level thing (note the beginning underscore+capital). It's not Standard C++, it's Microsoft implementation code, so I don't see any reason why a Standard C++ construct would have to do anything with it.